# Sort array based on another array and then on date

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know, I have an array of "Movie" objects with properties like production studio and release dates.

I'd like to sort the Array of objects based first on the on the ranking of the production studio and then on the date of each movie.

For Example:

```
studio_ratings = [Studio1, Studio2, Studio3, Studio4, Studio5]

array_of_objects = [Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4, Object5, Object6, Object7, Object8, Object9]
```

Each object have its date, so I can so `Object1.date_published` and `Object1.production_studio`, for example.

Comment: Can you give a larger model? What are the Objects? Is this strictly ruby or is it built on Rails?

Comment: It is strictly ruby, the objects are instances of a "Movie" class, wich have Title, Date, Genre, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that `studio_ratings` is the order you wish the studios to be ranked in. In which case you can do something like:

```
array_of_objects.sort_by {|obj| [studio_ratings.index(obj.production_studio), obj.date_published]}
```

But if you're doing lots of these, or the list of studios is long, you'd be better off constructing a hash instead of doing `.index` over and over. E.g.:

```
>> studio_rankings = ['Universal', 'Global', 'Local', 'Wolverine']
=> ["Universal", "Global", "Local", "Wolverine"]
>> class Film
>>   attr_accessor :studio, :date
>>   def initialize(studio, date)
>>     @studio = studio
>>     @date = date
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> films = [Film.new('Global', '2012-01-01'), Film.new('Universal', '2013-04-12'), Film.new('Global', '2011-10-10'), Film.new('Wolverine', '2008-01-01')]
=> [#<Film:0x101b101a0 @date="2012-01-01", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b10128 @date="2013-04-12", @studio="Universal">, #<Film:0x101b100b0 @date="2011-10-10", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b10038 @date="2008-01-01", @studio="Wolverine">]
>> films.sort_by {|f| [studio_rankings.index(f.studio), f.date]}
=> [#<Film:0x101b10128 @date="2013-04-12", @studio="Universal">, #<Film:0x101b100b0 @date="2011-10-10", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b101a0 @date="2012-01-01", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b10038 @date="2008-01-01", @studio="Wolverine">]
>> studio_index = {}
=> {}
>> studio_rankings.each_with_index {|studio, i| studio_index[studio] = i}
=> ["Universal", "Global", "Local", "Wolverine"]
>> studio_index
=> {"Local"=>2, "Wolverine"=>3, "Global"=>1, "Universal"=>0}
>> films.sort_by {|f| [studio_index[f.studio], f.date]}
=> [#<Film:0x101b10128 @date="2013-04-12", @studio="Universal">, #<Film:0x101b100b0 @date="2011-10-10", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b101a0 @date="2012-01-01", @studio="Global">, #<Film:0x101b10038 @date="2008-01-01", @studio="Wolverine">]
```